# Connecting a Logitech Broadcaster-type videocamera via USB

Tags: wireless-networking, webcam, camera

We have a videocamera from Logitech, a "Broadcaster" type, which we would like to use as a monitor camera in a ionizing radiation-protected area. The camera is meant to be used wirelessly and, to operate, it needs a Mac Os connected on the same wireless network. Our difficulty is that the camera should operate in a shielded environment where the wireless signal is essentially absent (the shield is intended for ionizing radiation, but wireless communication through the room walls is, consequently, very limited).

A possibility is to install a wireless router in the shielded area, but that is not going to do much good to the rest of our electronics in there. The Logitech Broadcaster camera, however, carries a USB port from which it can be re-charged. Could the USB connection be used to transport a video signal? The camera was not intended that way and there is no support for it, but connecting to the camera via USB reveals a file, stored on a small disk within the camera, indicating a MAC address. From here to a USB-streamed video is a long shot, perhaps.

Comment: What is the model of the camera?

Comment: It's called Logitech Broadcaster: http://www.logitech.com/it-ch/product/broadcaster-wifi-webcam